# BTA16 absolute maximum amperage at 220/240V 50hz and impact of snubbers on resistive loads?

Tags: arduino, power-electronics, component-selection

Using a BTA16 600CW3 triac with the arduino uno with the following schematic.
Can it derive a 1.5 ton Air Conditioner and what is the absolute maximum amperage and power it can handle safely at 220/240V. I am attaching the circuit for the fan dimmer I am using (inductive loads). All the resistors to the 240V are rated at 1 watt.
Neglect the zero crossing part, I wont be dimming it for the Air Conditioner. I just wanted to know whether the switching part can handle the current. And what is the max current it can handle? The datasheet says that it can handle 16A at 600V but I am not sure.

And I will also like to know (as said many a times that the snubbers are necessary) for inductive loads. What impact do they have on the restive loads. 
If I am unsure what type of load is to be connected than can I connect the snubber to the triac? 
[image]

Comment: The datasheet should tell you about the amps.

Comment: 1.5 ton AC? Sounds heavy!

Comment: Rated at 240Vs I don't think it more than 3KVA, so why not? If it gives 16A.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can handle 16A. Triacs are forgiving parts. Peak current can be ten times higher without destroying it.

The snubber may have the side effect of mains driven LEDs or neon lamps on the part light up though the thing is "off".

By the way: BTA16-600C**W** is a snubberless part. You simply don't need the snubber.

Comment: When you say "The snubber may have the side effect of mains driven LEDs or neon lamps on the part light up though the thing is "off"."

Comment: That is because the snubber bypasses the triac. It may be enough current to drive a neon lamp or a LED used for mains indication.

Comment: So for the inductive as well as the resistive load can I use this relay without the snubber or is the snubber necessary for the inductive loads like fan?

Comment: ** By relay I mean BTA16 as a relay. Also is the resistor configuration correct?  I was thinking of replacing the resistor configuration as 1k between MOC30121 PIN6 and MT2 and another 1k resistor between gate and MT1?

Comment: For resistive loads, you don't ever need a snubber. That circuit is for helping the triac turn off under inductive load. That is because turning off inductive loads gives a voltage peak which may make the triac trigger without a gate current. "Snubberless" triacs have a design which makes them withstand these breakover pulses.

Comment: What's MT1 and MT2? That's not on your datasheet.

Comment: I mean A1 and A2 (pin 1 and pin 2). Live connected to A2 and load connected to A1. Since it's a snubberless relay, so can i connect both resistive and inductive loads avoiding the RC snubber? Additionally, can I introduce an MOV instead of the snubber to my design?

Comment: The R/C configuration around U4 is correct. Don't change it.

Comment: Sure, so both resistive and inductive without snubber will do?

Comment: With BTA16-600C**W**, yes.

Comment: If the triac is tagged snuberless, this doesn't mean that it doesn't need a snubeber, rather it just means that the triac has no snubber, so you need to apply an external one.

Comment: @Marko Buršič: No. You may read some triac datasheets again.

Comment: Ok I have read, partialy you are right. Citation from ST AN439: Logic level TRIACs use the breakthrough of the Snubberless technology to improve the trade-off between sensitivity and commutation. Nevertheless, a snubber can still be
necessary with these TRIACs.